# Paradox of a corrupt court

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, state-of-israel, dina-dmalchusa-dina

With current events in mind ([South Africa v. Israel Genocide Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Africa_v._Israel_(Genocide_Convention))), I have a question. How does Torah help us solve the paradox of applying justice to an injust justice system?

If the court comes to an erroneous and therefore unjust judgement, how are we supposed to approach that? To flagrantly ignore it can harm justice, because it will encourage disrespect of justice systems. To abide by it would be to encourage the corruption of the court, as well as commit a direct injustice.

So what are we supposed to do? Seems like a lose-lose situation, and a bit of a paradox. If justice doesn't come from courts, and only courts have the power to pronounce judgements, then how can this problem be fixed? How can we even figure out what is true justice without a court?

I imagine the answer is different for Jewish court systems, vs. Jews having to abide by non Jewish court systems. It probably gets even more complicated when the Jews in question are secular. Due to current events I am interested in the latter, but to be honest, the entire subject of dealing with unjust courts is of interest so I would welcome answers that deal with whatever slice of this topic they want.

Comment: Note: this was just a breakfast musing on my part. I imagine this is the kind of thing that has been dealt with thoroughly before and I might just need to be pointed in the direction of some obvious source

Comment: Mistaken court rulings are discussed in tractate Horyot. Ruling against the court is Zaken Mamre

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks although this question is primarly focussed on קלקול הדין
 on an international level

Comment: That's not a thing you will find classical sources about

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe the answer is that when corruption of justice happens, there is no solution, and destruction falls upon the world: https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.33a.2

Comment: I'm not really understanding the premise of the question. Justice doesn't come from courts; it comes from G-d, Who created the entire concept of justice. If a court isn't acting in a just way, then it's not fulfilling its purpose. Would you think, after all, that the Sodomites were observing the Noachide Law of "dinim" with their court system?

Comment: @Meir it sounds like you are saying that if a court is corrupt, the only solution is personal intervention by Hashem?

Comment: No, properly speaking it would be up to human beings to do something about it. That what was expected of the citizenry of Shechem, for example, and since they failed to do so (and thereby were complicit themselves), Shimon and Levi did it for them.

Comment: @Meir what should be done if the ICJ rules in a corrupt manner against Israel, if Israel were to follow halacha?

Comment: @RabbiKaii there is a rule of "dina d'malchusa" but does that apply to international courts? I don't think so. All of the bases on which dina d'malchusa applies don't apply to an international court. I don't see any torah obligation to abide by the ruling of an international court at all. At that point it's just a pragmatic choice.

Comment: @Esther https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78823/does-dina-demalchuta-include-international-law

Comment: @RabbiKaii: ignore it, as any sensible Westphalian state would do.